# TypeError: onEmailBlur is not a function

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to call a function on blur but it show this error 
`TypeError: self._el_21.onEmailBlur is not a function`.  I have no Idea why it showing this because I use some question but it perfectly working fine.

### html

```html
<input type="email" required [(ngModel)]='inviteUser.email' 
(blur)="onEmailBlur()">
```

### component

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators }    from '@angular/forms';
import { UserService} from '../../services/user.service';
import { OnInit} from '@angular/core';   
@Component({
    selector: 'invite-user',
    templateUrl: '../../app/components/user/invite-user.html',
    providers: [UserService, HttpHelper, NotificationsService],
    directives: [MODAL_DIRECTIVES, SimpleNotificationsComponent]
})

export class InviteUserComponent {
    // InviteUserForm: FormGroup;

    isValidForm: Boolean = false;

    ngOnInit() {    


    }    
    public onEmailBlur() {
        alert('here');
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me. Maybe you made the same mistake I did when trying to implement your code a few minutes ago - I didn't start my compiler, so `onEmailBlur()` from `.ts` file wasn't compiled to `.js`, resulting in `onEmailBlur is not a function` error.

Comment: @MalikKashmiri You mean 'now'? :)